# read a database file with $.get + jquery mobile : not working on iOS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications

In a jquery-mobile web app, I read a txt file into an array using $.get :

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#welcome-page', function(){
    var request = $.get("proDB.txt", function(data) {
        var lines=data.split(/\n/);
    var i;
    prodata.push(0);
    var fieldnames=lines[0].split(/\t/);
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length-1; ++i) {
        var fields=lines[i].split(/\t/);
        prodata.push(i);            
        var j;
        prodata[i]={};
        prodata[i]['id']=i; //auto id, there is no more 'id' column in the DB file.
        for (j = 0; j < fields.length; ++j) {
            var str=fieldnames[j];
            prodata[i][str]=fields[j];  
        }
    }
    //SORT BY NAME
    prodata.sort(SortByName);

        alert("request"+request);

}, "text");
```

then later in the code, I make sure the $.get is done and I use the array :

```
request.done(function(){...
```

But the `alert` doesn't pop in safari's iOs, whereas it pops with the android browser and with desktop firefox.

Moreover, I am really unhappy with this as I would like to read the file once and for all in a separate function, and then be able to work on the array as much as I want.

Is there a cleaner way to ship with my app and read this text file into an array without having to worry if it's ".done" ? like with `pagebeforecreate` or something like that?
I have to mention that the file I am reading the data from, will have to be updated sometimes because his server-side clone will evolve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check mobile safari console output on present JS errors. If you start it in iOS emulator - this is the [guide of viewing js debug console](http://browsers.about.com/od/allaboutwebbrowsers/ss/iphonedebugger.htm)

Comment: thanks for your answer...I checked the errors and the file can't be found....it's weird because it seems that if I put the absolute path : www.mysite.com/files/proDB.txt it works...

Answer (score 0):

I discovered Ripple for Chrome, and I was able to debug with this.