# best practices to ship database file with web app and phonegap app

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am developping an HTML/CSS/JS app intended to be compiled by phonegap as well as to be used as is as a web app (directly on an online sever).

The application works with a database. For now it's a text file. I would like to avoid the ajax commands like `$.get` because [it doesn't work on iOS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894668/get-jquery-mobile-not-working-on-ios)

How can I ship this database with the application and read it in jquery, so that it works with phonegap as well a web app (included in offline mode using a cache manifest) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a webservice...

f.e. you create a central MySQL Database and get the Data via JSON. Now you're able to get your data with your Phonegap-app and your Web-app using JSON. If you want to use data offline you can use a SQLITE Database or your existing textfile.

Comment: Thanks @Sorm87 can you provide code for "MySQL Database and get the Data via JSON" ?

Comment: its long ago and i did it with the Zend Framework ... There are many tutorials out there how to  do this. For example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.json.html Zend support you etablishing a mySQL connection as well. You should try this way! Sorry for the late answer.